# How to fix position of Table header and scroll only Table body

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a table which has **tbody with 2 tr.** out of which 1 tr is for hide/show of data.

I want to fix position of Table header and scroll only table body. **Since i am using angular js ng-repeat on tbody I am not able to scroll table body**

I want output similar to this.
[Sample output with scrollable table body](https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/LNYrBd)

**But my Table structure is similar to this. Below is the code**

```
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="a in arr">
 <tr>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 </tr>
<tbody>
```

**HTML FILE**

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Edit</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Case ID</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Company Name</th>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="8"><input  class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Search ..." type="text" id="search" ng- 
                  model="search.compyNmeEnteredByBDO"/></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody ng-repeat="newOpportunity in opportunitycopy >

                <tr>
                  <td>
                <label> <input type="checkbox" value="" ng- 
                          model="newOpportunity.isSelected"> <span
                                class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon 
                         glyphicon-ok"></i></span>

                            </label>
                  </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                        {{newOpportunity.id}}   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{newOpportunity.compyNmeEnteredByBDO}} 
                    </td>




                </tr>

                 <tr ng-show="newOpportunity.hidestatus">

                    <td colspan="8">
                            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="ibox" id="mailbox-container">
                                <div class="mailbox-header d-flex justify-content-between"
                                    style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                                    <div>
                                        <h5 class="inbox-title">Details</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mailbox-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                                                <label>Quantum</label> <input type="text" readonly
                                                    class="form-control" value="{{newOpportunity.quntm}}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                                                <label>Remarks</label> <input type="text" readonly
                                                    class="form-control" value="{{newOpportunity.remarks}}">
                                            </div>
                            </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way by setting `position: sticky;`

```css
table thead tr th {
  background-color: orange;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
      <th>column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to try following.

Provide a height to your `tbody` and overflow for scroll `overflow-y:auto;` will give you a desire result.

Comment: I applied below height and overflow -y to tbody still not working                                                               table-fixed{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
   overflow-x:auto;
 tbody{
     height:100px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
  thead,tbody,tr,td,th{
    display:block;
   
  }
  tbody{
    td{
      float:left;
      text-align:center;
    }
  }
  thead {
    tr{
      th{
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
       background-color: #f39c12;
       border-color:#e67e22;
      }
    }
  }
}